# Does java have a class that represents a timer?

Tags: java, class-library

I'd like a timer class that allows me to call:

`.start()`   `.getElapsedTime()`   `.stop()`   `.reset()`

Does Java have such a class, or do I need to use my own (which I've already written).

From a best-practice point of view, I should use the Java class libraries classes if they exist, but I'm not sure whether this one does.

Can anyone give me a link to the javadoc for this class, if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `StopWatch` class in Apache Commons Lang.

> To start the watch, call `start()`. At this point you can:
>
> - `split()` the watch to get the time whilst the watch continues in the background. `unsplit()` will remove the effect of the `split`. At this point, these three options are available again.
> - `suspend()` the watch to pause it. `resume()` allows the watch to continue. Any time between the `suspend` and `resume` will not be counted in the total. At this point, these three options are available again.
> - `stop()` the watch to complete the timing session.
>
> It is intended that the output methods `toString()` and `getTime()` should only be called after `stop`, `split` or `suspend`, however a suitable result will be returned at other points.

#### API links

- [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)
- [`org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html)
- [The Common Java Cookbook - Measuring Time](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/lang-sect-measure-time.html)

  - With examples and further discussion

---

#### On using libraries

Yes, most definitely you should try to use good libraries whenever you can, instead of reinventing the wheel. The value of a well-designed, well-written, well-tested library is insurmountable, and Java has lots of it. The more users it acquires, the more mature it becomes, and any kinks would usually get fixed quickly.

#### Related questions

- [Most useful free third party Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-third-party-java-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

Java has a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class, but I suppose that you are looking for a [StopWatch](http://www.goldb.org/stopwatchjava.html) or a [Chronometer](http://silveiraneto.net/2008/03/15/simple-java-chronometer/). There are many implementations of these available in the net.

Comment: [this](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html#getTime(\)) looks close to what I want.

Answer (score -1):

About java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(), be aware of this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4290274

Comment: -1 for having no connection whatsoever with the question asked.

Comment: I know it was not stricly conneted but it was a warning. I worked with a platform based on java.util.Timer and there were big problems for this bug... a lot of money loss. Anyway I accept the -1